# Potential Energy of Point Charges in a Square

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, voltage

So, an AP Prep book for the Physics 2 test has the following problem: 
[image]
My reasoning is as follows:

The total potential energy = the sum of the PE of each of the 4 charges

Which will equal 4x the PE of one point charges

Therefore,

$$PE_{(total)} = 4 \times \frac{1}{4πε_0} \times ( 2\frac{q^2}{s} + \frac{q^2}{s \sqrt2})$$

Instead, they say that: (Problem#2:)
[image]
They have messed up many problems already in this book, but this would probably be their biggest mistake yet (most of the other ones were incorrect units).  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Given that they show their work, and you do not... What is wrong with their explanation? They have 4 terms for the edges, and 2 for the diagonals, and then simplify.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time you're wrong. You are overcounting the terms when multiplying by 4. Potential energy is given for two particles at a time, so you should be multiplying by 2, which is the same as multiplying by 4 and then dividing by 2.

Comment: You're welcome. Please refer to Duncan's answer for a more precise explanation of the physics behind my short answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Giorgio says, you are overcounting the terms when multiplying by 4.  I would like to elaborate a little bit, just to show how this is more than just a math error.  It is also a conceptual error:

You mention in your reasoning "The total potential energy = the sum of the PE of each of the 4 charges."  But this is false.  Not only that, but there is no such thing as "the PE of each of the 4 charges."  **The PE is not stored in the charges, but in the electric field.**  So one can speak of "the potential energy stored by adding a fourth charge to the other three charges" (this is the energy value which you multiplied by 4), but there is no physical reason that this would be 1/4 of the total potential energy of the electric field.

It is possible to solve this problem by considering one charge at a time, but to do so, you must "build" the charge configuration from scratch, starting with an isolated charge, then counting the added potential by adding a second charge, then the third, and finally the fourth.  Each charge will add more potential than the one before it.

Or you can take the mathematically simpler approach shown in the second solution you photographed.  It is just a bit harder to intuitively justify that method, but it is equivalent in the end.